# How to get all results from a Firebase Query in one block

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm having a hard time working with Firebase query results. With the following code:

```
     ref.queryOrderedByChild("gender")
        .queryEqualToValue("female")
        .observeEventType(.ChildAdded, withBlock: { snapshot in
        print("result: \(snapshot) ")
     })
```

The "result" is printed 3 times. I would expect a single array of all of the results (similar to a query on Parse) versus this being printed 3 separate times.

The end goal here is to append all of the results to an Array. However, I don't know how to do that, since I can't see any way of knowing how many elements will come back from the server.

I assume there must be something simple I am missing here.

Answer (score 2):

It appears it was something simple I was missing. Changing the event type from **.ChildAdded** to **.Value** resolves the issue. Hopefully this will help someone else...

```
 var resultArray:[AnyObject] = []
         ref.queryOrderedByChild("gender")
            .queryEqualToValue("female")
            .observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in

                for item in snapshot.children{
                    resultArray.append(item)
                }
                print("Results Array: \(resultArray)")
                print("Results Array Count: \(resultArray.count)")

         })
```

Comment: .value returns everything within a node; and if that's 1M children, you'll get all of them at one time. .childAdded on the other hand, returns each child, one at a time and also attaches an observer so that your app will be notified of any new children that are added.